# How to get the value of a label that have been set by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, telerik

This script is trigerred already on page load and label1 is set to "Hello World"

```
<script type="text/javascript">            
        function hello() {
           document.getElementById('<%= Label1.ClientID %>').innerHTML = "Hello World";
        }
</script>
```

when button clicked it return always null

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
     label2.text = label1.text; // always return null 
    }
```

Comment: Noway. You only can get values of `input` (plus `select` and `textarea`) elements, not `span`.

Comment: In order to retrieve value from dynamic JS (which is triggered at the page load event) you should probably use some kind of HTTP callback to the server.

Comment: Why would you set a value you _expect to be `POSTed`_ on a non-input field? If it _needs_ to be submitted, then look into something like a `hidden` input field (set it too/in addition to some front-end use case).

Comment: it's not the thing that i need to do eventually , i'm just posting a sample of my problem

Comment: _"it's not the thing that I need to do eventually"_ - Your question and posted code says otherwise. So if that's not what you want to do, then the server side code you posted - `protected void Button1_Click(...` is irrelevant....The basic thing to understand about `ASP.Net WebForms` is the `POSTback`mechanism (as the name implies, `POSTed` to server). Hth.

Comment: That said, the answer to your question therefore is "also via Javascript".